# Laravel-mix versioning when uploaded in S3 thinks in previous hash

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

With using `webpack-s3-plugin` npm package, I'm saving my laravel-mix compiled & versioned files into S3 (for cdn purposes).

Bare in mind, this was working until yesterday.

```
let webpackPlugins = [];
if (mix.inProduction() && process.env.UPLOAD_S3) {
    webpackPlugins = [
        new s3Plugin({
            include: /.*\.(css|js)$/,
            s3Options: {
                accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY,
                secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
                region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
            },
            s3UploadOptions: {
                Bucket: process.env.ASSETS_S3_BUCKET,
                CacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000'
            },
            basePath: 'assets/' + process.env.APP_ENV,
            directory: 'public'
        })
    ]
}

mix.scripts([   // I also tried '.combine'
    'resources/js/vendor/vendor/jquery.slimscroll.js',
    'resources/js/vendor/custom/theme-app.js',
], 'public/js/scripts.js')

// Other bundling stuff

.js([...].version()

mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: webpackPlugins
});
```

Now, S3's eTag doesn't match to `mix-manifest.json` hash. And, when I visit the page, it fetches 1 version behind, not the latest uploaded but exactly 1 previous version. However, when I check the 'updated date' on S3, it's correct. Nevertheless, it's exactly one version behind.

What I suspect is it is uploading to s3 before the bundling is completely done; however I am not sure. What am I missing here?

[image]

<sup>*I used [this guide](https://medium.com/@avosalmon/cache-busting-using-laravel-mix-and-cloudfront-s3-eb222b569f88) if you want to know the laravel side in detail.*</sup>

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I believe this is because you are using `mix.scripts`. It seems that only assets that are compiled using `mix.js` and CSS preprocessors are detected by the plugin. I have literally tried everything... I am getting to the stage where I may have to fork the repo. If you use the clean-webpack-plugin to remove the files before each build then you will notice that no files will be uploaded unless processed with the aforementioned processors. I suspect it may be to do with how Laravel mix utilises webpack because the plugin supposedly uses the build manifest...

Comment: It magically got fixed for me (or i couldnt figure out how it got fixed). If you find a solution, please let me know

Comment: I have made a minor amendment to the library and created a pull request. I am currently awaiting a new release to be done

Comment: To Laravel mix? would be nice if you can share it with me

Comment: No, to the S3 plugin. It is currently awaiting release but annoyingly the build is failing and I am not sure why, probably a unit test of some sort... If you want to manually fix it yourself, it is really easy (it's just quite dirty). Copy the S3 plugin minified source out of the node_modules directory and into your project, then search for the line `t.hooks.afterEmit.tapPromise` and change to `t.hooks.done.tapPromise`. Then reference this plugin in your webpack configuration. I know this is dirty but it should only be temporary until the latest version is pushed

Answer (score 1):

After diving around the S3 plugin source, I am fairly confident this is caused by the hook used to trigger the S3 upload. I don't know enough about webpack plugins to give a full description of this, but I have made an educated guess at what is causing the issue and my proposed fix seems to have sorted the issue.

The author of the plugin has accepted my pull request and the fix is currently awaiting release.

If you need a fix in the meantime, then you can do it like so (note, this is very dirty and should be treated as temporary):

1. Browse to your `node_modules` folder
2. Locate the folder named `webpack-s3-plugin`
3. Copy the file `dist/s3_plugin.js`
4. Paste somewhere in your project
5. Open the file and locate the line `t.hooks.afterEmit.tapPromise`
6. Replace with `t.hooks.done.tapPromise`
7. In your `webpack.mix.js` file, change the `require('webpack-s3-plugin')` to point to your javascript file

Just to reiterate, this is a **temporary** fix until the latest version of the plugin is released.

Comment: Great one! Thanks for the heads up and effort! Can you link the PR url please?